# PHP session dies after error in a POST request

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm having trouble with php sessions being deleted after a POST request.
If I submit a form with method POST, if on that page where the form redirects I get an error, and hit F5 to reload the page, the sessions get deleted.

Ok, so here's what I've done to recreate my problem:

I created a blank php project (server details below):

4 pages. Every page starts with session_start();

Page 1: store some value into a session:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
```

Page 2: simply output the contents of my session, just to see if it's still there.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['foo'];
```

Page 3: I created a simple form with method post that posts to page 4.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<form method="post" action="page4.php">';
echo '<input type="text" name="whatevs">';
echo '<input type="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

On page 4, I first tested it by simply doing print_r to $_POST.
But then I changed it to respond with error 500:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
exit;
```

So, here's what's happening:
I first go to page 1 to store a value in a session. I then go to page 2, just to see that my session value is stored.
Then I go to page 3 and submit my form to page 4. When page 4 returns status 200, everything's fine and works as expected.
But when I return error 500 as shown in my snippet, and then when on the error page I hit F5 to refresh the page, my session is gone. I then go back to page 2 to see if my session $_SESSION['foo'] is still there, and it's not. It's deleted. In fact, the PHPSESSID cookie contains a new ID.

If I do the same exact thing right away (go to page 1 to store a value, then submit my form on page 3), it won't delete it. If I give it a minute or so before submitting again, it will.

If I remove the error code and return normal status 200 with some text, this will never happen. Only when I return an error.

No other cookies are affected. They're all there. Only the sessions cookie is affected.

Another thing I noticed, is when I first get to page 4 and get my error 500, chrome's network window shows that I submitted my PHPSESSID cookie, just like on any page. When I do the fateful refresh on page 4, it looks like I'm no longer submitting the PHPSESSID cookie, and so the server's response now contains a new PHPSESSID cookie.

Server details:

Windows 10, running xampp with php 7.3.21

**Summary:**

Does anybody know anything at all about this? Why is this happening? Why only with POST? Why does it happen only on the first try, and then again only if I wait a minute or so before I repeat?
This scenario is a very basic recreation of a problem we're having on our website which would be way too complicated to describe here, so I distilled it down to this test case.

If anybody knows anything about the relationship between PHP's sessions, and POST request, and can shed any kind of light on this issue, it will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like everything should be working. Have you tried to check your error logs? Could be a config issue or conflict.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out, this has to do with the cookie's "samesite" configuration. Since now, by default it's set to "lax", rather than "none", it won't send cookies with a POST request if you refresh the page after a non 200 response.

Not 100% on the details, but it turns out that it has to do with the samesite=lax configuration.